Producing quadrature signals using single MCU timer and single OC register per channel
Using a microcontroller timer, is it possible to produce the following signals:

With the following constraints:

use only one timer (can count up or down or up and down)
output compare channel has only one comparison register
no software interactions after the initial setup

I don't want to couple the question to any particular MCU, but you can think of STM32 timers as an example.
I would say it is not possible, but maybe I am not seeing some clever register configuration.

Unlikely with the restrictions you have. However there might be a MCU with special abilities that makes it possible. Such as programmable logic.

Some TI C2000 microcontrollers contain a Configurable Logic Block (CLB). The application report How to Migrate Custom Logic From an FPGA/CPLD
to C2000™ Microcontrollers gives an overview of the capabilities. Posting as a comment to give a suggestion, and not an answer, as haven't checked if will meet all the constraints.

At what frequency would you these signals?

@Antonio51 Why would it matter? At any frequency supported by the timer.

Then, simple timer working under interrupt and outputting 2 signals in one defined byte (b00011110) would do it (shifting 2 bits, 4 x).

If the signal is not high-frequency, within 1-1000 Hz, you can try to reinitialize the comparison register and the timer polarity in the interrupt callback function "on the go".

That idea is against the "no software interactions" so it does not qualify.
